# Simple math expression solve in objective c from left to right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math

I simply have this expression in objective c NSString: @"10+5*2".
I wanted to solve this expression automatically and came across to a solution:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:expression];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

The above works well but it produces a result: 20.
Actually this evaluates the "*" first means first it does 5*2 = 10 + 10.
But I want to remove this precedence and simply wants each operator having same precedence with left to right so that answer could be 10+5 = 15 * 2 = 30.

Although writing own function is the last option but I really don't want to mess-up with the string functions. I would like to use something built in.

Thanks,

*********** Working solution ****************

Thanks for all your help Eiko and Ozair!!
Based on their answers I have written this bunch of code which works perfectly for me!

```
NSString *expression = lblBox.text; // Loads the original expression from label.
    expression = [expression stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@")+"];
    expression = [expression stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@")-"];
    expression = [expression stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@")*"];
    expression = [expression stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@")/"];


    NSUInteger count = 0, length = [expression length];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length); 

    while(range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range = [expression rangeOfString: @")" options:0 range:range];
                 if(range.location != NSNotFound)
                 {
                     range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
                     count++; 
                 }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        expression = [@"(" stringByAppendingString:expression];
    }


    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:expression];
    [webView release];
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@",expression, result);
```

Comment: can you modify the string or is it coming from a user or another system?

Comment: What about using parenthesis?

Comment: @Ozair: I am creating this string by using buttons and labels.

@marzapower: I don't want any parenthesis, this would be evaluated from left to right without any precedence.

Comment: If you want to look more into math expression evaluation, this guy has gone in depth http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/6196535272/parsing-mathematical-expressions

Comment: Why not do the calculation directly when building the string?

Comment: You might reconsider adding parentheses, since there's no built-in way to evaluate ignoring precedence, but it's fairly simple, if you are constructing that string, to also construct a string with parentheses that force left-to-right evaluation.

Comment: @Eiko: I am not calculating directly when building the string because there is a back key too which deletes the last digit or operator and = sign can be pressed any time hence calculating while pressing the "=" would be good to go. If you find more better option please let me know.

Comment: If you use a JavaScript interpreter, it's going to interpret using JavaScript precedence rules. So you need to construct the string with that in mind. Even if you want to display without parentheses, there's no reason you can't have different strings. But since you actually want something much simpler than what the JS parser provides you should probably consider coding that simple thing directly. Indeed, since you're building the expression from button presses, there's no good reason why you need to parse a string at all.

Comment: @andyvn22: Adding parentheses means again writing a bunch of code for adding parentheses behind the scene for the string which is as complex. yet thanks for suggestion. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if it's the same as [@Ozair Kafray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382725/simple-math-expression-solve-in-objective-c-from-left-to-right/6382905#6382905) says...

For each operator that you append to the string, add a `)` first and add the matching `(` at the beginning. I.e.

```
10
(10 ) +
(10 ) + 5
((10 ) + 5 ) *
((10 ) + 5 ) * 2
```

Just make sure that when deleting an operator to also delete the parentheses as well.

Comment: +1 for illustration!
I hope there is a way to do this once the string is formed. Is there?

Comment: If you don't want to build in parallel, you could replace every operator with ")operator", then add the matching number of "(" at the beginning. May be easy if there are only a couple of operators available, and you get the number of operators by comparing the lengths of the strings.

Comment: Awesome idea!
You are great!
Just trying to find out that how can I get the number of operators in string.
Any way that's another story.
Thanks,

Comment: That is easy. Compare the length of the original string with the length after replacing with the ")operator". Each replacement just added one character.

Comment: @Eiko: Yes, its almost the same except that I was not adding `)` after the first operator.

Comment: Ozair is correct. Kindly consider voting up his answer too cause both answer share the credit and share the answer. :)

Comment: +1 for the illustration really. Though my answer was the same, I was thinking about how should I illustrate it since I don't really know how to write code in Objective-C. Turns out that I didn't need to know Objective-C to have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

No built in way to do this that I know of. I think you will just have to roll up your sleeves and write a function. If you want to use objective-c then use NSScanner.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
Could you please help me about how NSScanner works and how it could help in situation?

Comment: As always, Apple's docs do a much better job of explaining it then I ever could: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147-BCIEFGHC

Answer (score 3):

As from your answer to my question in comments, you are generating the string during input. I would suggest that you add a parenthesis after every operand except the first one.

So you do not add anything to string after `10`, then the operator `+` is added. After that for each operand that is `5` add a closing parenthesis `)` and a corresponding opening parenthesis `(` to the start of string. Similarly after `2`. This way you won't have to write anything of your own for processing the string.

Comment: Amazing!!
But I am using a delete key too hence at the time of writing I think doing this parenthesis stuff could lead into a problem hence I want it once the string written. I wish is there a way to do this parentheses work once the string is completed?

Comment: No need for the special case of the first operator. It will just add unnecessary code complexity.